# How do I solve this question without squaring both sides?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am building a program that will need to calculate unit vectors some angle away from each other. To begin, a unit vector of the form ($x_1,y_1,z_1$) is input. It sets $x_1 = x_2$ because there will be infinitely many solutions otherwise and now there will just be 2. I set $z_2 = \sqrt{(1-x_1-y_2)}$ because it will be a unit vector and then solve for $\cos \theta = v_1 * v_2$ to find $y_2$.

After a few short steps I ended up here and thought I would be just fine squaring both sides.

$\cos \theta - x_1^2  - y_1y_2 = z_1^2\sqrt{(1-x_1^2-y_2^2)}$

note that $x_1,y_1,z_1,$ and $\theta\ $ are all known at this point in the calculation.

A few steps later I arrived at the quadratic equation and thought I was done...

What ended up occuring was that my python program is now spitting out warnings every other time it runs a calculation based on this. because the quadratic equation answer is irrational.

How can a fix this to account for the squaring I need to do to solve it? I now realize a $+-$ pair will be generated in that squaring step but I do not know how to carry it through to the end when the python program uses it to calculate $y_2$.

Comment: Setting $x_1=x_2$ doesn't look reasonable. For example, suppose $(x_1,y_1,z_1) = (1,0,0)$. If you set $x_2=x_1$, then your second unit vector must also be $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Is Python is complaining about irrational or imaginary numbers?

Comment: Have you looked up rotation matrices or euler angles?

Comment: Agree with Théophile. Setting $x_2=x_1$ is not always possible, and is the root cause of your difficulties. If $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors with first component equal to $x$, then their inner product will be at least $x^2-(1-x^2)=2x^2-1$. So if $\cos\theta<2x^2-1$ your method won't give any solutions. The extremal case $x=1$ makes this plain.

Comment: Théophile and Jyrki Lahtonen: I had not thought of that. Ugh, this project keeps getting more difficult. How would you suggest I go about solving for the generic form of my problem? I am doing this to generate bond angles in the field of computational chemistry. It will need to generate up to 4 vectors (although later it may need to be up to 6) that are all a certain minimum angle apart. An example would be the tetrahedral bond geometry of carbon. There are 4 bonds and each are 109.5 degrees apart at minimum.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I am getting the error "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt" when I run the quadratic equation.

Comment: Is there some other constraint that you can bring into play to winnow down the possible solutions?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the input vector? You can generate a perpendicular axis via cross product with a standard basis vector, then rotate about that axis by the required angle. It’s not even necessary to generate a full rotation matrix if you go this route.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to take the square root of a negative number.  This would lead to a complex number.

Comment: Ok. The extra context helps. For example the tetrahedral structure is already very rigid. Once you have two unit vectors, the remaining two are already uniquely determined (ok, they can trade places). I would probably just use a fixed tetrahedral set of vectors, say $(1,1,1)/\sqrt3$,
$(-1,-1,1)/\sqrt3$, $(-1,1,-1)/\sqrt3$ and $(1,-1,-1)/\sqrt3$, and rotate the whole system so that the first vector points at the desired direction. Are you familiar with the linear algebra of rotations?

Comment: For systems of 6 vectors you can use similar ideas. If there will be some wiggle room with the angles, then it becomes a bit more complicated. May be you can begin with a planar set of six vectors at 60 degree angles to the adjacent ones in the xy-plane, and then perturb them to increase the angles further. Like giving the odd numbered vectors a small positive z-coordinate and similarly giving the even numbered vectors a small negative z-coordinate. Then rotate the entrie system to fit together with the rest of the molecule or whatever.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I believe this is what I will do. I am somewhat familiar with rotation vectors (I have taken the class linear algebra and differential equations) but have not practiced it. My new plan is to make unit vectors for each molecular geometry and rotate them so that one points to the bonded atom.

Answer (score 1):

Given a unit vector ${\bf u}=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, taking the cross product with the unit vector $(1,0,0)$ yields the vector $(0,z_1,-y_1)$ perpendicular to ${\bf u}$, and you can scale that to a unit vector ${\bf v}$. Then the vector ${\bf w}$ in the plane spanned by ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ that is at an angle $\theta$ to ${\bf u}$ is given by 
$${\bf w}={\bf u}\cos\theta+{\bf v}\sin\theta.$$
Of course this doesn't work if $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(\pm1,0,0)$, in which case you can take any other vector not parallel to it.